# How to set a proxy in rubys net/http?

Tags: ruby, http, proxy, net-http

I'm trying to set a proxy and to use it in a simple get request like in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).
But I always receive an error!
The adress and port are right with open-uri it worked.. it's
`http://proxy:8080` .

```
proxy_addr = 'proxy'
proxy_port = 8080

Net::HTTP.new('google.de', nil, proxy_addr, proxy_port).start { |http|
  # always proxy via your.proxy.addr:8080
  Net::HTTP.get('google.de', '')
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Net::HTTP.new('google.de', nil, proxy_addr, proxy_port).start { |http|
```

This will create an `http` object for you to use in the block. Use that rather than generating new ones each time, here `Net::HTTP.get('google.de', '')`

```
proxy_addr = 'proxy'
proxy_port = 8080

Net::HTTP.new('google.de', nil, proxy_addr, proxy_port).start { |http|
  # always proxy via your.proxy.addr:8080
  http.get('google.de', '')
}
```

Comment: What if you need authentication?

Answer (score 33):

There is another option:

Net::HTTP will automatically create a proxy from the `http_proxy`
environment variable if it is present.

So you can use

```
ENV['http_proxy'] = 'http://172.16.3.160:4226' # your http://address:port here
```

and Net::HTTP will use it for all requests by default.

It can be helpful for net_http requests in third-party libraries (for example it works for gem [gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) for [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)).

Pass `nil` for the proxy address to disable default `http_proxy`.

Comment: A little clarification: `Net::HTTP` will automatically use `http_proxy` environment variable only when called through `Net::HTTP.new`. Using `Net::HTTP.start` will not use `http_proxy`environment variable because it passes `nil` for the proxy address if not specified (instead of passing `:ENV`).

Comment: @cbliard Good point. Though, you can still use auto-discovery of proxy in `NET::HTTP.start` by using `NET::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port, :p_port => :ENV)`.

Comment: @Aert using `:p_port => :ENV` works, but I do not like its readibility :). Another thing to notice: username and password from `http_proxy` are not read (like in `http://username:password@address:port`).

Answer (score 12):

Here is the code that works if you are making a REST api call behind a proxy:

```
require "uri"
require 'net/http'
    
proxy_host = '<proxy addr>'
proxy_port = '<proxy_port'
proxy_user = '<username>'
proxy_pass = '<password>'
    
uri   = URI.parse("https://saucelabs.com:80/rest/v1/users/<username>")
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_host,
                         proxy_port,
                         proxy_user,
                         proxy_pass)
    
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)

req.basic_auth(<sauce_username>,
               <sauce_password>)
    
result = proxy.start(uri.host,uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
    
puts result.body
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried all above but not working.

my final scripts is like below (work for me):

```
url = "https://host.com/url"
proxy_url = "http://proxy.com:port"

# split important values
uri = URI(url)
proxy_array = proxy_url.split(":")
proxy_protocol = proxy_array[0]
proxy_addr = proxy_array[1]
proxy_addr = proxy_addr[2 .. proxy_addr.length - 1]
proxy_port = proxy_array[2].to_i

# new objects
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port)
result = proxy.get(uri);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#

require 'rubygems' 
require 'net/http' 
require 'open-uri' 
require 'timeout' 


mimvp_url = "http://proxy.mimvp.com/exist.php"
mimvp_url2 = "https://proxy.mimvp.com/exist.php"
mimvp_url3 = "https://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery-i18n/1.1.1/jquery.i18n.min.js"

$proxy = '183.222.102.95:8080'

$proxy_addr = $proxy.split(':')[0].strip
$proxy_port = $proxy.split(':')[1].strip

puts $proxy_addr
puts $proxy_port


begin 
  Timeout.timeout(30) {

    # mimvp_url = http://proxy.mimvp.com/exist.php
    # uri.host = proxy.mimvp.com
    # uri.port = 80
    # uri.path = /exist.php
    uri = URI.parse(mimvp_url)
    result = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, nil, $proxy_addr, $proxy_port).start { |http|
      http.get(uri.path)
    }
    puts result.body


    # mimvp_url = http://proxy.mimvp.com/exist.php
    # uri.host = proxy.mimvp.com
    # uri.port = 80
    # uri.path = /exist.php
    # req = #<Net::HTTP::Get:0x007fafa594ff78>
    uri = URI.parse(mimvp_url)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    result = Net::HTTP::Proxy($proxy_addr, $proxy_port).start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http| 
      http.request(req)
    } 
    puts result.body


    # proxy auth （NO TEST）
    $proxy_addr = '<proxy addr>'
    $proxy_port = '<proxy_port'
    $proxy_user = '<username>'                # 代理用户名
    $proxy_pass = '<password>'                # 代理密码

    $website_username = '<website_username>'  # 目标网站登录用户名
    $website_password = '<website_password>'  # 目标网站登录密码

    uri = URI.parse(mimvp_url)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    req.basic_auth($website_username, $website_password)

    result = Net::HTTP::Proxy($proxy_addr, $proxy_port, $proxy_user, $proxy_pass).start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http| 
      http.request(req)
    } 
    puts result.body

}
rescue => e  
    puts e.inspect  
    exit  
end
```

Comment: More than posting some code, explain what your code does. The SO focus is more than giving the solution, but to teach who is asking for help how things work.

Comment: you can directly run the code, use $browser->proxy(%proxy); to set proxy ip:port address