# How can I run a ruby script with a proxy?

Tags: ruby, http-proxy

**Example:**
The ruby script "TwitterConverter.rb" connects to the twitter api and subscribes to the TwitterStream.

**Problem:**
The script runs on a local Windows machine that sits behind a corporate proxy. Hypothetically, the script doesn't support proxy configuration.

**What I've tried so far**
1. I ran the script on my notebook, with the proxy disabled - the script worked fine
2. I've researched on the topic "How to start a ruby script with proxy" - without any success
3. I've set the environment variables correctly (http_proxy, https_proxy, both lower- and uppercase. https://user:pw@proxy.domain.com:port)

**Question:**
How can I start a ruby script with a proxy? The solution should be within the code. (Solutions for Windows settings are appreciated, but off-topic)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15792999/2230115 to me.
Do the answers there answer your question?

Comment: Isn't that only for Net::HTTP? I need something that works for all Gems. @iCodeSometime

Comment: It's not really possible to have something that works for all gems. A gem can work however the author wants. They could even even compile their own networking code from C, or shell out to the command line and use curl or similar

Comment: It sounds like what you might be looking for is a transparent proxy. This runs at a deeper level than other proxies, and will force all network traffic to go through the proxy without any application specific settings https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/